# Hostname not working with Laravel (Lumen) installation on Vagrant

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, vagrant, apache2

I'm able to access my [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com) installation on Vagrant via IP in the browser, but when I try accessing it through a custom hostname it redirects to `http://mysite.dev/public` and triggering a 404 error.

- `http://192.168.33.10` works as expected
- `http://mysite.dev` redirects to `http://mysite.dev/public` and throws a 404 error: `NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 443`.

I'm on OS X running [Scotch Box](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box) through Vagrant VM.

Any ideas? Here are (potentially) relevant files.

**vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder "~/Documents/projects/mysite", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

end
```

**/private/etc/hosts**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.33.10   mysite.dev
```

**/my_site/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: Try `http://mysite.dev`

Comment: Why should mysite.local even work - you didn't put it in the hosts file? :)

Comment: Whoops ;) That was simply a typo in my question! Appreciate the sanity check though. I've edited the question.